# How to obtain pid from Process without illegal access warning with Java 9+?

Tags: java, reflection, process, pid, java-9

I need to obtain the underlying OS PID for a Process I start. The solution I'm using now involves access to a private field through reflection using code like this:

```
private long getLongField(Object target, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field field = target.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    long value = field.getLong(target);
    field.setAccessible(false);
    return value;
}
```

It works but there are several problems with this approach, one being that you need to do extra work on Windows because the Windows-specific Process subclass doesn't store a "pid" field but a "handle" field (so you need to do a bit of JNA to get the actual pid), and another being that starting with Java 9 it triggers a bunch of scary warnings like "WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred".

So the question: is there a better way (clean, OS independent, garanteed not to break in a future release of Java) to obtain the pid? Shouldn't this be exposed by Java in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of the [`Process#pid`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#pid()) introduced in Java9, a sample of that would be as:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "Hello World!");
Process p = pb.start();
System.out.printf("Process ID: %s%n", p.pid());
```

The documentation of the method reads:

```
* Returns the native process ID of the process.
* The native process ID is an identification number that the operating
* system assigns to the process.
```

and noteworthy as well from the same

```
* @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the Process implementation
*         does not support this operation
```

Comment: Nice little addition to Java 9.  Note that this might trigger an `UnsupportedOperationException` if the platform doesn't happen to support exposing the process ID.

Comment: @MarkPeters Yes, you're right. I'd updated with the documentation as well.

Comment: Nice, I should probably have RTFM :)
Is it known on which platforms this is supported currently? Win/Mac/Linux I expect?

Comment: Not very sure about the general guidance over the platforms it supports. Yet, I can confirm using this on Mac for sure. @OlivierGérardin

Comment: You can assume that it will work on all platforms where the Reflection hack worked in the past (as that’s a sign of an availability of a pid). But it’s also worth looking at the methods `toHandle()` and `info()` and their returned [`ProcessHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) and [`ProcessHandle.Info`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.Info.html) APIs. Perhaps, you don’t need the pid anymore, as whatever you want to do with it, can now be done directly with a Java API…

Comment: @Holger I store the pid in a file to manage long-running jobs, a pattern commonly found under Unix and Unix-like OSes, so I do need the pid...

Comment: @OlivierGérardin Well, then you need the pid, but that’s exactly what this new support is for.